# Google Charts: Custom Ticks

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I would like to set my own ticks on the horizontal axis of a Google Chart. I included hAxis.ticks (as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)) in my attempt below, but it refuses to work since the ticks are still not integers even though I specified them to be.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
          data.addColumn('number', 'myNumber');
          data.addRows([
            [1,17],
            [2,18],
            [3,20]
          ]);
          var options = {width: 800, height: 500, hAxis: {ticks: [1,2,3]}};
          var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));
          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options)); 
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ticks` is not a supported option for *material* charts.

*material* --> `google.charts.Line` -- `packages:['line']`

*classic*  --> `google.visualization.LineChart` -- `packages:['corechart']`

you would need to use a classic chart.
note: there is an option for classic charts to have a **similar** look...

```
theme: 'material'
```

you can find the full list of unsupported options here...
[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: Sorry completely forgot once I continued fiddling with plots, but this worked great, thank you!